# Exporting by table

Tags: import, sql, export

I am using PHPmyAdmin to move a site. 
My site is too large to use the single file export/import method. (I know how to do it, it works fine on smaller sites.)

It seems the only thing working for me is to export, and then import, a table at a time. 30 tables. This is ok for a one time move, but this method for ongoing backups is pretty crazy. Anyone know how to **export all tables, but in separate files?** i.e. instead of the one big dbxxxx.sql, I want each table e.g. wp_posts.sql to export one after the next.

Answer (score 1):

While not directly answering the question, I would strongly recommend you use a DB management application. phpMyAdmin IMO is a nightmare to work with, and as you have discovered, very difficult to manage large files.

If you are on a Mac [Sequal Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) is a really amazing app. If you don't have external access to MySQL it supports SSH tunnelling so you can SSH to the DB server / a server with access to MySQL. You will be able to import / export pretty much any size DB with that.

If you are on windows, I have used a couple of different programs, I would recommend [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/). It can also do SSH tunnelling (little more effort required).

Comment: +1 for great idea. I do have Macs, but my host is FTP only. SSH is the next level of account. I may go ahead and upgrade.